# How to minimize console window?

Tags: c++, windows, console

I am running a C++ console application,
for some period of time,

I want to minimize the window in which my application is running.

for eg. I launch myApp.exe from cmd. Then its launched in new window.

So what are libraries which can minimize the window in which application is running.

Application doesnt have any GUI

Comment: I don't know if it is relevant for your problem, but I would préfère to separate things : make the app à simple console app that doesn't even know the console API and launch it via `start /min myApp.exe` (supposing you are running on Windows ...)

Comment: This seems good idea, I ll try this! Actually one of my use cases is to minimize during runtime and restore

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suppose your application is running on Windows (this is not portable across different operating systems).

You have first to get handle of your Console window with [GetConsoleWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, then you can use [ShowWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to hide/show it as required. Ddon't forget to include `windows.h`:

```
ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_MINIMIZE);
```

Instead of `SW_MINIMIZE` you can use `SW_HIDE` to completely hide it (but it'll flash visible once when application just started).

Note that if you have control over process creation you can create it as `DETACHED_PROCESS`: a detached console application does not have a console window. `CreateProcess()` function has also other workarounds you may be interested in (for example you may create a child process for outputting...)

**UPDATE**: as follow-up of [Patrick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38424934/1207195) you may change the subsystem from Console to Windows and then, if you require to write to console, create a new one using [AllocConsole](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
if (AllocConsole()) {
    printf("Now I can print to console...\n");
    FreeConsole();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to change

Properties... | Configuration Properties | Linker | System | Subsystem

from **Console** to **Windows**.
However, you then need to add a WinMain() entry point, such as:

```
  int __stdcall WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int)
  { int argc = 0;
    LPWSTR* argv = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLine(), &argc);    
    return Main(argc, argv);
  }
```

assuming unicode.  To avoid confusion, I rename the console's wmain() function to something like Main(), as above. Of course printf no longer has a console to write to.