# In lazarus is there a way to maximise the console using code

Tags: windows, console, pascal, lazarus

I'm using lazarus, I want to try make the console window maximised, I already have code to change the properties, but I would also like to be able to maximise the window in the code as well.

Comment: Which console? Windows console? Xterm on cygwin? OS X terminal ?

Comment: That's not quite what i'm going for, I instead want to maximise the window, The question you posted edits the property of the console, oh and @Marco van de Voort its windows, sorry for not addressing that in the question.

Comment: *I instead want to maximise the window, The question you posted edits the property of the console*. Your question title says *console*. So what window are you talking about? If you're talking about a window application and the main window of your program, you should just have to set the property of the window.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, thanks for the advice, I figured it out,
I used the answer from [How to minimize console window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23514897/how-to-minimize-console-window) changing the code from:

```
ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_MINIMIZE);
```

to

```
ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_MAXIMIZE);
```

which seemed to do the trick. Simple but it hadn't even occurre to me to try it before now.

Comment: This is a perfect example of the importance of reading code in order to understand it, rather than blindly copying it